# Queries on subsequence of string

Tags: java, string

Given a string S and Q queries, each query contains a string T. The task is print “Yes” if T is subsequence of S, else print “No”.
I am trying to learn algorithms and implementing them.
I have written the below code in Java :

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class QueriesOnStringSubsequence {
    public boolean subSequence(String original, String query) {
        Stack<Character> s1 = new Stack<Character>();
        Stack<Character> s2 = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
            s1.push(original.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(s1.peek());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i++) {
            s2.push(query.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(s2.peek());
        }
        while (!s1.isEmpty() || !s2.isEmpty()) {
            Character s1Top = s1.peek();
            Character s2Top = s2.peek();
            if (s1Top == s2Top) {
                s1.pop();
                //System.out.println(i);
                s2.pop();
                return true;
            }
            System.out.print("True");
        }
        System.out.print("False");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueriesOnStringSubsequence ob = new QueriesOnStringSubsequence();
        ob.subSequence("geeksforgeeks", "gg");
    }
}
```

I tried to debug this and in Eclipse and it won't go into the if condition. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong.

Comment: Does it work with `s1Top.equals(s2Top)`?

Comment: No it won't work with that

Comment: You pushed all the elements of `original` and `query` into stacks so whats at the top of the stack is the last element of each string. When you use `peek()` you compare `s` and `g`  and because of that you don't enter the `if` and remain in an infinite loop.

Comment: Is `ob.subSequence("geeksforgeeks", "gg")` supposed to return true or false in your assignment?  I thought it should be false (because geeksforgeeks" does not contain the subsequence "gg"), but it looks like you approved of an answer that returns "true" for the above input.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `Stack` are LIFO data structures.

This means when you run:

```
Character s1Top = s1.peek();
Character s2Top = s2.peek();
```

You are getting the last two characters added. In this case `s` and `g`.

This means that the `if` statement will not be met. The second time the software loops since you are using `Stack.peek` the element is looked at but not changed. Therefore your `while` loop is looking at `s` and `g` over and over. Since they are never equal your `if` will never be met and therefore your `while` loop will be infinite.

Also you are checking:

```
while(!s1.isEmpty() || !s2.isEmpty())
```

This means both need to be empty before exiting which can cause an issue. I believe you want to use:

```
while(!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

As duncan pointed out, a stack may not be the best data structure for this. I assume you want to go in order which means that you should use a queue.

Here is an implementation. I used better variable naming conventions which help not only in readability, but also debugging.

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueriesOnStringSubsequence {
    public static void subSequence(String original, String query) {
        Queue<Character> originalQueue = stringToQueue(original);
        Queue<Character> queryQueue = stringToQueue(query);

        while (!originalQueue.isEmpty() && !queryQueue.isEmpty()) {
            Character originalQueueHead = originalQueue.peek();
            Character queryQueueHead = queryQueue.peek();

            if (originalQueueHead.equals(queryQueueHead)) {
                queryQueue.poll();
                System.out.print("YES");
            } else {
                System.out.print("NO");
            }

            originalQueue.poll();
            System.out.print("...");
        }
    }

    private static Queue<Character> stringToQueue(String input) {
        Queue<Character> queue = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            queue.add(input.charAt(i));
        }
        return queue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueriesOnStringSubsequence.subSequence("geeksforgeeks", "gg");
    }
}
```

> YES...NO...NO...NO...NO...NO...NO...NO...YES...

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. I was tyring to implement queue after understanding that stack was not the best Data Structure for this case. This helped me.